# Start Co-op on Disney Infinity for Wii U

Tags: wii-u, disney-infinity

My daughter got a second character for Disney Infinity (Venelope and she already has Wreck-it Ralph).  Allegedly you can play co-op like this in Disney Infinity.  But we have a second controller and hit + and we cannot get it to switch to co-op mode.

Any ideas what we might be doing wrong?

Does anyone have an exact step-by-step of how you do it?  (This doesn't exist online after searching for hours.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We finally found the answer.  You must have a Nunchuk connected to the controller.  If you don't, it doesn't tell you in any way.  It just won't connect at all.

Also, I found that it never works on the Wii version, except in Toy Box, but that limitation does not apply to the Wii U.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. Thanks for following up and answering your question!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge - or as far as I have read about it - local coop in Disney Infinity is only possible within the "Toy Box"-mode, unless spending money:

To play local coop, you will have to buy another figure that belongs to one of the sets, as only figures from the same set can play in that mode.

The "Starter Set" only has one figure frome each set.

Comment: As stated in the question, we purchased a second Wreck-It-Ralph character.